# What exactly is "repocheta"?

Tags: palabras-raras, definiciones, nicaragua, comida

Another food related question I collected on my trip through Central America five years ago is

> repocheta

Again it's not in Wikipedia, Wiktionary, Larousse Gran Diccionario, Google Translate, or the DRAE. [It is included in a list in the Wikipedia article about Nicaraguan cuisine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicaraguan_cuisine), but it's a red link with no details.

Does anybody know what "repocheta" is, and if it is peculiar to Nicaragua or if it's also a dish in other Central American countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the *Diccionario del Español de Nicaragua* published by the Academia Nicaragüense de La Lengua (I have a printed copy, I can't find it online), it's a type of food consisting of fried tortilla with beans and cheese along with cabbage salad, onion, sour cream, ketchup, and vinegar:

> **repocheta.** f. Tortilla frita acompañada de frijoles y queso, aderzada con ensalada de repollo, cebolla, crema, salsa de tomate y vinagre. || **2.** Tortilla doblada en forma de empanada y rellena de queso.

[Photos](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cordeliahall/5477095616/in/photostream) of *repocheta* can be easily found online, just search!

Comment: Yes photos were easy to find but to us silly gringos so many tortilla dishes look alike. Plus this is the Spanish SE not the cooking SE and I wanted exactly your answer - so thanks! (-:

Answer (score 5):

When I lived in Nicaragua I learned how to make repocheta. From what everyone's saying I'm going to assume it is a Nicaraguan recipe. It seems that no one has heard of it outside of Nica.

You would cook up a batch of red beans (I always put a clove or two of garlic in mine).

Then you would blend them up with a couple of bell peppers, tomatoes, and an onion, until they're pretty smooth, and start frying them in some oil to make frijoles licuados. (Warning - splattering is a problem).

I usually let mine go for an hour or so until they've darkened in colour. That's when the flavour really deepens.

I also make a cabbage slaw which has finely shredded cabbage and carrots, chunks of cucumber and tomato, in a salt/vinegar brine.

Last, spread the frijoles licuados on a tostada (a big corn chip), top with cabbage slaw, and then dollop some sour cream on top. That's Nicaraguan repocheta.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if repochetas is just for Nicaragua. I never heard any other country from centra america that they made repochetas.

Repochetas at home we made it with beans, cheese (not the cheese from US) and cabagge salad.  Cheese from central america is very different from other regions.

Repochetas can have different styles like those that jrdioko presented in his post. This is another one [repocheta casera](http://foodieinternational.com/portfolio/repocheta-de-la-casa)

Answer (score 1):

Just that it's a corn tortilla with cream and cheese, and as far as I can find out, only ever appears on Nicaraguan sites / recipes.

[An example recipe for it is available online too](http://www.jcplayzone.com/Country/Index.asp), if you wish to reminisce ;)

Answer (score 1):

I am Nicaraguan. A repocheta is a torilla filled with queso fresco and deep fried. All the beans and other stuff are just how they're served.

Answer (score 1):

I am from Nicaragua. Let me explain you. There are two kinds of `repochetas`, both of them are made up of fried tortilla (corn tortilla).

The difference is that one of them is first fried without folding, when it is fried you put on it crushed red beans on one side of the tortilla, then add cabbage salad mixed with tomatoes slices and vinegar, add sour cream and crushed cheese.

The other one is made in this way, put crushed cheese on the tortilla, fold it on the half, as a semicircle, and then fry it. Serve it with cabbage salad mixed with tomatoes and vinegar on the `repocheta`, if you want put sour cream and ketchup on.

I hope you could understand.